# How can i get all information from <tr> in which django checkbox is active

Tags: python, html, django, checkbox

I have such a table on my website that is filled with data:

```
     <table
    id="table"
    data-height="540"
    class="table table-dark">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th data-checkbox="true"><input name="btSelectItem" value="selected_data"></th>
                <th data-field="id">ID</th>
                <th data-field="email">Email</th>
                <th data-field="source">Source</th>
                <th data-field="created_at">Created at</th>
                <th data-field="modified_at">Modified at</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
<script>
        var $table = $('#table')

        $(function() {
            var data =   {{data|safe}}
            $table.bootstrapTable({data: data})
        })
    </script>
```

it is located in the tag of the form with the post method, with the help of this code fragment, I receive information about active checkboxes when the button is pressed:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
    mails = request.POST.getlist('btSelectItem')
```

I have a question, can I get all the information from this  tag, or at least if the checkbox is active, get information from this field:

```
<th data-field="id">ID</th>
```

I would be very grateful for any advice)

Comment: How do you populate the table? You only show the header?

Comment: I have added the padding code

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm sorry, but could you look at it again?